# What diet can be appropriate for a person with obesity, diabetes, hypertension and chronic kidney disease?

Tags: nutrition, diabetes, hypertension, obesity, kidney-disease

At my place of work as a student trainee, my attention was called to a patient who has suffered badly from secondary diseases.

- He has a Body Mass Index of 42, obese.
- He also suffers from Type 1 Diabetes (Insulin dependent)
- His blood vessel walls have become narrow, causing an increase in blood pressure (Hypertension)
- He has Chronic Kidney diseases: bowman capsules are not able to filter his blood properly because of the pressure.

Can this Patient be helped by a diet? We would have to place him on:

- little carbohydrates because of his obese stature and diabetes
- low salt because he is hypertensive
- low protein because of his Kidney disease

Yet what's left to eat if valid nutrients are not to be put up for consumption?

Comment: Well, low salt still means sufficient salt to live, but nothing more. Same goes for carbohydrates - you won't starve an obese patient to death!

Comment: @Narusan - Yes, actually, you can. In the absence of food, life threatening starvation occurs around 40-50% of weight lost. Fatal in 8-12 weeks with no food intake. Less if no water intake

Comment: @JohnP Sorry for that misunderstanding: I meant that any diet for patients - no matter how severe the obesity - will still have to cover the bare minimum. That’s what I meant by „low salt still means sufficient salts to live“. Likewise, low calorie intake should never be starve them to death. Therefore, even on a low carbs diet, they can still it carbohydrates, albeit maybe just the bare minimum.